# Send variables between php scripts

Tags: php

I´ve two php scripts: **main.php** and **script.php**.

I´m sending a variable `$id` from main.php to script.php.
In the script.php file I´m using this variable `$id` to get certain data out of a MySQL database. This data is stored in the variable `$bonusspellid` and needs to send back to the main.php file.

For transfering the variables between the two files I´m using `session_start()` but I get a `"503 GET error"` when opening the main.php file.

What is the right way to transfer the both variables between the scripts?

**main.php**

```
session_start(); 

$id = "458";

$_SESSION['id'] = $id;

// receive variable from script.php:

$bonusspellid = $_SESSION['bonusspellid'];

echo $bonusspellid;
```

**script.php**

```
session_start(); 

// receive variable from main.php:

$id = $_SESSION['id'];

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "xxxxx", "xxxxxx", "xxxxxx");
$conn->set_charset("ISO-8859-1");

$sqlitemeffect = "SELECT * FROM ItemEffect WHERE ID IN (?)";

$stmt60 = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt60, $sqlitemeffect)) {
    echo "SQL Failed";
} else {

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt60, "s", $id);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt60);
    $resultitemeffect = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt60);

    while($rowitemeffect = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultitemeffect)) {
        $rowsitemeffect[] = $rowitemeffect;
     }
}

$bonusspellid = $rowsitemeffect['0']['SpellID'];

 // Send variable to main.php 
 
$_SESSION['bonusspellid'] = $bonusspellid;
```

Comment: Session_start should be at the beginning of the php. Everything else after.

Comment: I´ve changed it but no effect.

Comment: How do you open the files? Are there any errors there? I cannot find where you open/call the other php-file

Comment: These are the complete scripts. So maybe that´s the mistake. How do I call the other php file?

Comment: You can call `header("Location:script.php"); exit();` (and similar for main.php). Note that these header-calls are not "returning". So you won't get back to the calling point afterwards. It simply opens another php-file and executes it

Comment: I don't get it, how do you expect do to have those variables ? do you want to do it with 1 HTTP call? why don't `include` the script into your main file ?

Comment: I agree with @Frankich. You should use include or require to include the script.php... and also use a function to call from main.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need session variables for your code. Try this:

```
// main.php
require_once("script.php");
$id = "458";

$bonusspellid = get_bonus_spell($id);;

echo $bonusspellid;
```

And then your script.php:

```
// script.php
function get_bonus_spell($id) {
   $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "xxxxx", "xxxxxx", "xxxxxx");
   $conn->set_charset("ISO-8859-1");

   $sqlitemeffect = "SELECT * FROM ItemEffect WHERE ID IN (?)";

   $stmt60 = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

   if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt60, $sqlitemeffect)) {
       echo "SQL Failed";
   } else {
       mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt60, "s", $id);
       mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt60);
      $resultitemeffect = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt60);
 
      while($rowitemeffect = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultitemeffect)) {
         $rowsitemeffect[] = $rowitemeffect;
      } 
   }

   $bonusspellid = $rowsitemeffect['0']['SpellID'];

   return $bonusspellid;
}
```